# checkbox selection and removing columns in datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, checkbox

My DataGridView doesn't work well. This is my code, I only want to display 4 columns with the first column being a checkbox column.

```
        Dim dt_zone As DataTable
        Dim iCounter As Integer

        dt_zone = obj_aims_zone.get_row_for_display("", area_id)
        dvg_selected_group_list.DataSource = Nothing
        If dt_zone IsNot Nothing Then
            If dt_zone.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                dvg_selected_group_list.DataSource = dt_zone
                For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dvg_selected_group_list.Rows
                    If row.Cells(3).Value.ToString.Equals(group_id) Then
                        row.Cells(check.Index).Value = True
                    End If
                    row.Cells(1).ReadOnly = True
                    row.Cells(2).ReadOnly = True
                    row.Cells(3).ReadOnly = True
                    row.Cells(4).ReadOnly = True
                Next
                For iCounter = 1 To 7
                    dvg_selected_group_list.Columns.RemoveAt(5)
                Next
            End If
        End If
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are having?

Comment: And can you tell something about the dt_zone data source? The code you have shown looks like it should do what you want, though it isn't how I would have written it.

Comment: my problem is checkbox didn't check and columns that i remove is not remove, in datagridview ,shows the whole data in dt_zone ,  i want to display only 4 columns with checkbox column each

Comment: my dt_zone has 11 columns , i want to display first four columns of dt_zone table with check box each , check box value is depend on dt_zone column 3th valuse.

Comment: i put dvg_selected_group_list.DataSource = dt_zone to form_load() and the rest of coding(adding check box value true, remove columns) to button_click() , it's work fine . but putting that two things together is not vorking

Comment: above coding is put in form_load() ,that code work fine in first time ,but next times the datagridview shows all the data in dt_zone. i use showdialog() .

Answer (score 0):

I know this was from awhile ago, but it would seem easier to delete the columns you don't want with:

```
dataGridView.Columns.Remove("column name")
```